# C++ Single function pointer for all template instances

Tags: c++, templates, macros, function-pointers

Is there a concise way to point to all instances of a templated function without using macros?

I have several templated functions that I want to test across a variety of types:

```
template<typename T>
void function1() {
  return;
}

template<typename T>
void function2() {
  return;
}

template<typename T>
void function3() {
  return;
}
```

I can do this with a macro:

```
#define TEST_ACROSS_TYPES(fn) \
fn<int>();  \
fn<bool>(); \
fn<char>(); \
fn<double>(); \

TEST_ACROSS_TYPES(function1);
TEST_ACROSS_TYPES(function2);
```

But, (1) Macros are ugly and hard for others to follow, and (2) I'm using `CATCH`, which doesn't play nice when using macros to set up test cases.

Is there a way to do something like this:

```
void testAcrossTypes(SomeType f) {
  f<int> ();
  f<bool> ();
  f<char> ();
  f<double> ();
}
```

which seems much cleaner, except for the problem of defining `SomeType`.  This question ([How to define typedef of function pointer which has template arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14848924/how-to-define-typedef-of-function-pointer-which-has-template-arguments)) explains how to define a pointer to a templated function; but, requires that the template arguments be specified.

---

For clarification:  Imagine `function1`, `function2`, and `function3` each test a different templated function.  Each function needs to be tested for `int`, `byte`, `char`, `double`, etc.  I want to avoid having to explicitly set up many (i.e. num_functions * num_types) tests for each function.  Instead, I want to have a single method that points to the test function (`function1`, `function2`, etc.) and runs it for each template type, thus consolidating

```
function1<int>();
function1<byte>();
function1<char>();
function1<double();
...
function2<int>();
function2<byte>();
function2<char>();
function2<double();
...
function3<int>();
function3<byte>();
function3<char>();
function3<double();
...
```

into just one call per test function

```
testAcrossTypes(function1);
testAcrossTypes(function2);
testAcrossTypes(function3);
```

Comment: XY-Problem? I don't get what you're after.

Comment: I'm trying to find a solution to this problem:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38491608/test-c-template-class-using-catch-framework.  Specifically, I'm trying to replace the macro with plain code.  The example strips away the testing details.  Imagine `function1` tests a templated function.

Comment: Running _what_ actually?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are trying to accomplish with

```
void testAcrossTypes(SomeType f) {
  f<int> ();
  f<bool> ();
  f<char> ();
  f<double> ();
}
```

would be possible if `SomeType` could be a template template argument. However, the standard does not allow function templates as template template argument.

From the C++11 Standard:

> **14.3.3 Template template arguments**
>
> 1 A *template-argument* for a template template-parameter shall be the name of a class template or an alias template, expressed as id-expression.

Your best option is to use functors instead of functions. Example:

```
template<typename T>
struct function1
{
   void operator()() {
      return;
   }
};

template<typename T>
struct function2
{
   void operator()() {
      return;
   }
};

template < template <typename> class F>
void testAcrossTypes() {
  F<int>()();
  F<bool>()();
  F<char>()();
  F<double>()();
}

int main()
{
   testAcrossTypes<function1>();
   testAcrossTypes<function2>();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can accomplish it by means of a type-erased functor, like the one in the following example:

```
#include<vector>

template<typename T>
void function1() { }

template<typename T>
void function2() { }

template<typename T>
void function3() { }

struct Test {
    template<typename T>
    static void proto() {
        function1<T>();
        function2<T>();
        function3<T>();
    }

    void operator()() {
        for(auto &f: vec) f();
    }

    template<typename... T>
    static Test create() {
        Test test;
        int arr[] = { (test.vec.emplace_back(&proto<T>), 0)... };
        (void)arr;
        return test;
    }

    using func = void(*)(void);
    std::vector<func> vec;
};

void testAcrossTypes(Test test) {
    test();
}

int main() {
    testAcrossTypes(Test::create<int, bool, char, double>());
}
```

It's easy to modify in both cases:

- New functions require to be added to the `proto` static member method and that's all
- Adding a new type is a matter of using it when call `create`, as shown in the above example

The functor will keep in charge of creating the N*M calls to be executed.
Moreover, you don't need to move your functions in a bunch of structs to be able to use them.

Comment: Very interesting.  Can you explain more about this part:  `(test.vec.emplace_back(&proto<T>), 0)...` (especially the `...`)?

Comment: @Zack The ellipsis unpacks the parameter pack `T`. It's a trick to work around the fact that fold expressions are to come yet. What's the doubt exactly?

Comment: This is my first C++ project in many years.  I hadn't seen that syntax before and didn't know what it was called.